# Starting each SQL record from a specific point

Tags: sql, window-functions

I am wanting to figure out how to start each record from a specific point in SQL. I have created a data set to try and represent what I would like.

This is the starting data set.

[image]

However, I want to get a new view, with a defined starting point.

[image]

So each member record starts from ID 33 onwards, ordered by Member and Date. Basically want every record after ID 33 and the corresponding date for it.

Comment: You mean something like `... where ID>=33`?

Comment: Adding pictures as data is not a good idea. PLEASE add your sample data and expected result.

Comment: @StephanBauer I've just amended the photos. The ID's aren't always progressively bigger. I want to select the row where ID = 33 and it's corresponding date. Then everything from and after that date for each member. Sorry, I should've made this clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your ids are in order, you can use:

```
select t.*
from t
where id >= 33
order by member, date;
```

If the ids are not in order, one method is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where date >= (select min(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.member = t.member and t2.id = 33);
```

And finally, a windows function approach is:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(case when id = 33 then date end) over (partition by member) as date_33
      from t
     ) t
where date >= date_33;
```

Comment: I've just amended the original question, as I want the date from the ID=33 and all rows after that date for each Member

Comment: @MWong . . . That is what all but the first answer does.